# Video will not redirect in IE

Tags: video, redirect

Have produced a short video which redirects to a download page at the end.

The redirect works fine in Firefox
But for some reason I cannot get the redirect to work in IE.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you are redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

Include http:// to your ru= param?

ru= is not some standard flashvar, so if that doesn't work you should try show the actionscript code (or reference to your player's documentation).

Also, if you want to add code, you don't have to add it to a comment. Just edit your question.